# How to address multiple spines in matplotlib 3.5?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/spines_api.html) says that I can address multiple spines at once by passing in a list like so:

```
spines[['top','right']].set_visible(false)
```

I wanted to set the linewidth of my spines so I wrote

```
panel2.spines[["top","bottom"]].set_linewidth(0.72)
```

and got a TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. I don't understand the issue.

Here is a minimal working example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.patches as mplpatches
import numpy as np 

plt.figure( figsize=(1,1) )

panel1=plt.axes( [0.1,0.1,0.5,0.5] )
panel1.spines[["top","bottom"]].set_linewidth(2)

plt.show()
```

Where replacing the list with just "top" or "bottom" string works.

Comment: Your code seems to work without problems in matplotlib `3.4.1`. The functionality seems to be new since `3.4.0`. Maybe you want to upgrade?  (`3.5`isn't released yet. In version 3.3.5 released in 2014, you'd need two separate calls to `.set_linewidth()`.) Also note that in Python, `False` starts with a capital `F`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm new to Python/Jupyter/Matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the suggestion by @JohanC:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.patches as mplpatches
import numpy as np 

plt.figure( figsize=(1,1) )

panel1=plt.axes( [0.1,0.1,0.5,0.5] )
# Specify each side independently.
panel1.spines['top'].set_linewidth(2)
panel1.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(2)

plt.show()
```

Reference:
[How to remove the frame from a Matplotlib figure in Python](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-remove-the-frame-from-a-matplotlib-figure-in-python)